# jFile:move does not cause any error while it's failing to move the file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I actually managed to make an installation zip for a plugin that I made and in the installation script file, I included this code in the install function in order to copy some file in a folder within joomla in another directory.

```
class plgVmCustomPayeddownloadsInstallerScript {

   function install($parent) {

        $src = "plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php";
        $destination = "components/com_virtuemart/controllers";     
        if(!JFile::move($src, $destination,JPATH_ROOT)){
            echo "tried to move from ".$src." to ".$destination;
            return false;
    }
}
```

After the installation I keep getting an error in joomla, "unable to rename the file" and the file that was supposed to be moved commanded by the install function did not, despite the fact that the files within the installation.xml did actually get coppied and installed correctly.

Also within the installation script In the install function I included some sql which is executed normally without any problems.

and I also tried in the postflight function with no success.
Also I do not get any specific erros from the php_error.log

I also tried to create this weird test, with the above tester.php file in my root application of my joomla installation.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Set flag that this is a parent file.
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

// Mark afterIntialise in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;

// Route the application.
$app->route();

// Mark afterRoute in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;

// Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch();

// Mark afterDispatch in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null;

// Render the application.
$app->render();

// Mark afterRender in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null;


    //plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php to 
    //components/com_virtuemart/controllers
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $src = JPATH_ROOT."/plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php";
    $destination = JPATH_ROOT."/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/";        
    echo $src."<br>";
    echo $destination."<br>";
    JFile::move($src,$destination);

?>
```

The file does not get moved from payeddownloads to controllers folder and it is not causing any error.

Also I need to mention that php.ini has error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = On.
Also the php_error.log captures the errors. If I type for example echo "lala"oo it will log the error and it will show it.
So I suspect that JFile::move has a bug and its not throwing any errors even though the file is not copied. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead. Few tweaks make to your code:

```
function install($parent) {

    $src = JPATH_SITE . "/plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php";
    $destination = JPATH_SITE . "/components/com_virtuemart/controllers";

    if(JFile::exists($src)){
       echo "File Exists!";
    }
    else{
       echo "File Doesn't Exist!";
    }
    if(JFolder::exists($destination)){
       echo "Destination Folder Exists!";
    }
    else{
       echo "Destination Folder Doesn't Exist!";
    }

    JFile::move($src, $destination); // Move file

    if(JFile::move($src, $destination)){
       echo "File Successfully Moved!";
    }
    else{
       echo "failed to move from ".$src." to ".$destination;
    }

}
```

Comment: no, its not working and no error. I also added else statement and it moved to else like it is successfully moving it. I also managed to show hidden files just in case, but no :( its not even hidden. 
I also tried jFile::copy but your if fails and it echos the tried to move.. . any other suggestions? thanx for your help btw

Comment: I also did, if(!JFile::exists($src)){echo "file does not exist in $src<br>";} and it echos , but I see the file :(. I wana die

Comment: @themhz : updated my answer. I think I rightly remember you have to use JPATH_SITE to define the paths when moving files

Comment: now it echos "tried to move from /var/www/joomla25test/plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php to /var/www/joomla25test/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/"

Comment: I also added a test.txt in the folder and tried to move that just in case there is something about .php files. but I get the echo again

Comment: what permissions does the file and folder containing it have? should be: **folder=755** and **file=644**

Comment: err, the paths are 100% correct, even if I am tired we are 3 people here pulling our hairs to this. My permissions are 777. I will change them

Comment: never make them 777 ;) Im trying a few moew things. I'll update my answer when I have something

Comment: sorry I am not good at linux, its sudo chmod -R 755 var/www for folders and sudo chmod -R 644 var/www/*.php for php files?

Comment: yes, all folders should be 755 and files should be 644. Making anything 777 is a security risk and some hosts prevent anything from being done if they are set to this

Comment: Ok I added permissions 755 to the folders and I also added permissions just to that file 644 because I don't know if I can do it recursively to all files. But I am sure that for the sake of the test, they do have those permissions. I also did the test On my windows machine but I get the same results.

Comment: hmm that's really odd. Only thing I can think of is trying to copy the file then deleting the old one instead of trying to move it. Sorry I can't be of anymore help

Comment: You did light up some darkness and I will keep on testing to see whats going on. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Even thought the thread is old, I found it having the same issue, maybe the solution could work for anybody else.

JFile::move requires a source and destination FILE path. In the above code the paths should look like follows.

```
$src = JPATH_SITE . "/plugins/vmcustom/payeddownloads/payeddownloads.php";
$destination = JPATH_SITE . "/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/payeddownloads.php";
```